# merge by groups of rows

Tags: r, merge

In R, i would like to do a special merge. 
I have two datas: data1 and data2.

> data2

```
> group code product
    24   1     car
    24   2     bus
    25   1     potato
    25   2     rice
```

> data1

```
> group code   member
    24   1      Joseph
    24   2      Mary
    25   1      Amanda
    24   1      Brenda
    24   2      Jane
    25   2      Lee
    24   1      bruce 
    25   1      peter
    25   2      rice
    25   2      steven
```

I would like to merge by code but by groups too. Something like this

> merge_data

```
> group code   member     product
    24   1      Joseph      car 
    24   2      Mary        bus
    25   1      Amanda      potato
    24   1      Brenda      car
    24   2      Jane        bus
    25   2      Lee         rice
    24   1      bruce       car
    25   1      peter       potato
    25   2      rice        rice
    25   2      steven      rice
```

I can create a new column paste0(group,code) for merging the two datas... but i would like to know other alternative(elegant), maybe only one merging function with special parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `merge` does what you want:

```
merge(data1, data2)
   group code member product
1     24    1 Joseph     car
2     24    1  bruce     car
3     24    1 Brenda     car
4     24    2   Mary     bus
5     24    2   Jane     bus
6     25    1 Amanda  potato
7     25    1  peter  potato
8     25    2    Lee    rice
9     25    2   rice    rice
10    25    2 steven    rice
```

By default, `merge` will match same-named columns in each of its input data frames.

Comment: ..and in more complex scenarios, you can pass a vector of columns to the `by=` argument, i.e. `merge(data1,data2,by=c("group","code"))`